# Type erasures in Xamarin binding library

Tags: c#, xamarin, type-erasure, indoor-positioning-system

I created a binding library for IndoorAtlas. I am successful so far in creating an app except when loading the floorplan. I am having problem with the generated C# classes specifically with the abstract method fetchFloorPlanWithId. The SDK documentation describes it as follows:`abstract IATask<IAFloorPlan> fetchFloorPlanWithId(String floorPlanId)`

However the generated C# method is 
`public abstract IATask FetchFloorPlanWithId(string p0)`;

I tried casting it as 
`(IATask<IAFloorPlan>) mResourceManager.FetchFloorPlanWithId(id)` but I am getting an invalid cast error

I need help pointing me to the right direction in solving this issue.

Below is the generated C# class for the IAResourceManager

```
[Register("com/indooratlas/android/sdk/resources/IAResourceManager", DoNotGenerateAcw = true)]
public abstract class IAResourceManager : Java.Lang.Object
{
    [Register(".ctor", "()V", "")]
    public IAResourceManager();
    protected IAResourceManager(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer);

    protected override IntPtr ThresholdClass { get; }
    protected override Type ThresholdType { get; }

    [Register("create", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/indooratlas/android/sdk/resources/IAResourceManager;", "")]
    public static IAResourceManager Create(Context p0);
    [Register("create", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/os/Bundle;)Lcom/indooratlas/android/sdk/resources/IAResourceManager;", "")]
    public static IAResourceManager Create(Context p0, Bundle p1);
    [Register("fetchFloorPlanWithId", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/indooratlas/android/sdk/resources/IATask;", "GetFetchFloorPlanWithId_Ljava_lang_String_Handler")]
    public abstract IATask FetchFloorPlanWithId(string p0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED. I solved it by directly editing the generated C# classes and interfaces in the binding library project